# Re-read httpd.conf without downtime

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

Is there a way to get Apache to re-read the httpd.conf without downtime?

I am running a web service that a number of users need to stay connected to, however I have recently made some changes to `httpd.conf` which will not be re-read by Apache unless it is restarted. Each restart inevitably causes issues for some users resulting in a series of technical support calls however, according to [LPI Linux Certification in a nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005283.do):

> The *httpd* daemon will respond to the *HUP* signal by rereading its configuration files. If you've made changes and want *httpd* to reconfigure itself, send it the *HUP* signal:
>   `$ kill -HUP 'cat /var/run/httpd.pid'`

I looked into the in-built [`taskkill`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602%28WS.10%29.aspx) and `Stop-Process` commands but it doesn't allow for different signals. My guess is that `SIGHUP` isn't supported by Windows but haven't found any hard evidence against this. Perhaps there is a much simpler solution I have missed.

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible using the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

More info on: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/apache/restart-apache/

On Windows, you can try:

```
httpd -k restart
```

Although I believe doing a graceful restart isn't supported on Windows. More info on: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#wincons

Comment: The question is about Apache on *Windows*.